# Can't get Rust types correct

Tags: types, rust

```
use std::num::Float;

fn main() {
    for i in 1..101 {
        euler(i)
    }
}

fn euler(x: i32){
    let n: i32 = x;
    let e: f64 = (1.0+(1.0/n)).powi(n);

    println!("Euler's number where n = {} is {}", n, e);
}
```

I have this code and I can't get it to compile. I'm pretty new to Rust so help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a concrete issue with the compiler error message that you need help with? Maybe you don't understand how the error message is phrased or terms it uses? You should **include** the error message and then tell us what part is causing you trouble. Otherwise, this question looks like *"I don't know how to read error messages"* and is liable to be closed for lack of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the error message:

```
<anon>:11:28: 11:29 error: mismatched types:
 expected `_`,
    found `i32`
(expected floating-point variable,
    found i32) [E0308]
<anon>:11     let e: f64 = (1.0+(1.0/n)).powi(n);
                                     ^
```

Here, Rust has **very good** messages: you need to provide a floating-point variable, not a integral one:

```
let e: f64 = (1.0+(1.0/n as f64)).powi(n);
// HERE                ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Seems to work. I thought 1.0 would make it choose f64 but I guess not.